# About layout, how to keep actions performed on the menu, in a new browser tab or window, with Thymeleaf and Spring?

Tags: spring, menu, fragment, thymeleaf

For example, in the GMAIL layout, let's suppose now I'm seeing the contents of the "inbox" and in parallel, in the side menu, the "category" menu was opened. Then if I open a new browser tab or window with the exact same URL, the "category" menu remains open (last action). How to do this with Thymeleaf and Spring? Is there somewhere a code snippet with this example? I looked at some things about Thymeleaf (fragment) and Ajax, but didn't see an example that would fit 100% when I open a new tab or window.

Step 1, Viewing the Inbox
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4k8wV.png)

Step 2, seeing the "inbox" and just opening the "category" menu (note the URL doesn't change)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ZfkP.png)

Step 3, open a new tab, then put in the same URL as in step 1 and the page result is same life as in step 2
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ZfkP.png)

Answer (score 0):

When the user takes an action like opening the category menu, you have to save the state of that menu.  The two options you have are:

- A cookie (which could be set w/javascript when the user clicks the category link).
- Setting the currently selected menu option in the session (which would have to be an ajax call, since you can only access/change session with a call to the java server).

Once you've decided how you want to store the currently selected menu item, you just need to read it back when the user reloads the page.  It doesn't matter whether or not it's a new tab or window, so long as it uses the cookie/session when displaying the new page.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.